# pdflatex doesn't find package although it is installed

Tags: errors, texlive

When I am running

```
pdflatex template.tex
```

I get the error

```
! LaTeX Error: File `xstring.sty' not found.
```

However, I have downloaded the package myself and placed it in a latex-folder:

```
$ find . -name "xstring.sty" 2>/dev/null
./usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/xstring.sty
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: Could you have two TeX systems installed? What do `command -v pdflatex` and `kpswhich xstring.sty` report?

Comment: if `kpsewhich xstring.sty` has no output then run `texhash` and try again. If it has again no output then there is something wrong with your TeX directories.

Comment: you should never place files under the standard tex directories "by hand" it just confuses your package manager, you should do `tlmgr install xstring`

Comment: xstring is not an oberdiek package. Don't put it there. The standard location if installed with tlmgr is tex/generic/xstring.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: The standard location of `xstring.sty` is  `/tex/latex/xstring/`, Only the  `xstring.tex` should be in the generic directory.

Comment: @Red-Cloud not in my texlive -- I checked. If this is wrong someone should report it.